# apache POI exception in reading xlsx files

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

I'm using apache POI for reading **xlsx** files by adding below dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm getting following exception while running with jetty plugin even if deployed in tomcat.

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
......

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
...........
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.readFrom(StylesTable.java:121)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.<init>(StylesTable.java:92)
    ... 186 more
```

I removed the xmlbeans dependency as the maven will automatically download poi dependencies , still the same exception.Any help?

Comment: Also got this error  using `3.11` and `3.12 beta`

Comment: Did you try [reading the Apache POI FAQ entry on this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Answer (score 15):

I used poi with version 3.12. The following dependency is also required:

`compile 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1'`

see also http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025

Comment: From the link: There are two jar files available. The full jar of all of the schemas is ooxml-schemas-1.x.jar and smaller poi-ooxml-schemas jar is only about 4mb. This latter jar file only contains the typically used parts though.

Comment: latest version: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cooxml-schemas%7C1.3%7Cjar

Answer (score 4):

I have made it run for these dependencies:

```
     def poiVersion='3.9'
     compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:'+poiVersion
     compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:'+poiVersion
     compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:'+poiVersion
```

When I try for others it does not work:

3.10 : is not known to maven central

3.11 : fails, with exact the error in this case !!!

Conclusion POI 3.9 works !!!!

Comment: I am failing with the same errors, and have the same experience when adjusting versions, except that my "`ClassNotFound`" is `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList`. Does anyone know if this is reported as a bug in `poi-ooxml` 3.11?

Comment: this answer is misleading its not that poi 3.12 is broken, you need to include full ooxml-schemas dependency. Note there are two similarly named jars. see Aliaksandr Pyrkh's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I tried using `poi 3.10`, `3.11` and `3.12 beta` with Grails and get this error as well.

After downloading and including http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.0/ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I use 3.7 but have you try adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Getting the same exception even after adding this dependency, even i tried 3.7 version but in vain.

Comment: For 3.7, I have it working with poi-3.7, poi-ooxml-3.7, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7, xmlbeans-2.3.0, geronimo_stax_api_1.0 and dom4j-1.6.1

Comment: Even after adding all the dependencies you mentioned same exception.

Comment: I am having this exact problem. I've added all these libraries to my filepath. I'm using this with oracle's OAS.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to inconsistency is the poi jars.
You can download latest jars and it will start working.

you can add latest jar files for all below:

Commons-compress ,
ooxml-schemas ,
poi-scratchpad ,
poi-ooxml ,
poi ,
poi-ooxml-schemas ,
dom4j ,
poi-excelant