# Grails 2.5.2 and Apache POI - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: grails, apache-poi

I need to export some data to Excel from a small Grails application. To do so, I have added the following dependencies to my BuildConfig:

```
    dependencies {            
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.13'
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.13'
    }
```

Whenever I try to utilize the libraries, I run into a ClassNotFoundException. The following code reproduces to error:

```
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Title")
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0)
    // Make first header row:
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Header1")
```

The call to `row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Header1")`
Produces the following stacktrace-message:

```
Class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message
org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList
```

Originally I only included the `poi-ooxml` but a jar-finder search suggests that the class is included in `poi-ooxml-schemas`, so I included that as well. It still doesn't work however. The code compiles fine and the error occurs runtime.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something or what?

Comment: poi-ooxml requires poi as in https://poi.apache.org/overview.html . Add `compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.13'` to your dependencies

Comment: It's seems to be downloaded and added as a transitive dependency and it makes no difference to add it explicitly ..

Comment: So I think this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330593/apache-poi-exception-in-reading-xlsx-files . Read http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025 , maybe you need to use full schemas jar

Comment: You are exactly right. I chose to downgrade to 3.9 instead of using the 14+ mb of full schemas... And now it works! :)

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate post of: [apache POI exception in reading xlsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330593/apache-poi-exception-in-reading-xlsx-files)

Two solutions:

- Downgrade to 3.9
- Use the full schemas jar file (~15mb)